# Sigmoidal programming

Tags: constraint, docplex, gurobipy

I plan to use sigmoidal programming from the git repo https://github.com/madeleineudell/SigmoidalProgramming.jl

There are some issues with the implementation of this repo. It requires me to pass $A, b, C, d$ from the equation set ($Ax\le b$) and ($Cx=d$). It is really difficult to construct these matrices because docplex or gurobipy output matrix in sparse format. Moreover they have equality and inequality embedded in the same matrix with slacks I think. So to decouple them into $A$ and $C$ and correspondingly $b$ and $d$ vectors. The initial plan was to use gurobi or cplex to construct the equations and export the matrices and right hand sides but it's getting more difficult.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Given you're using a Julia package, can you use [JuMP](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/) to get what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I got a workaround it.

- I exported my model from python doplex in .mps format. The equation
  name should not have any spaces because that later creates issues for
  reading mps files.
- The using JuMP package in Julia, I read the mps file.
- The default syntax for constraints in JuMP is LB <= Ax <= UB and there are functions to get A in sparse form, LB and UB.  Using collect() I convert sparse to dense matrix.
- Then I do something
  stupid and smart,  I vertically stack(using vcat()) constraint matrix
  as a = [A, -A] and rhs = [LB,-UB] and then pass it as aX<=rhs  The
  equality is implicitly captured where LB and UB are same.
  Inequalities have one of the bounds as Inf or -Inf
- Basically what I do is, LB <= Ax <= UB ===> -Ax <= -LB and Ax <= UB which is equivalent to a = [A, -A] and rhs = [LB,-UB] in equation ax <= rhs
- This is simple to
  do but doubles the number of constraints so might be a stupid thing
  to do for large problems unless there is some pre-processing also
  being done.